# Ethernet cord is connected to Macbook Pro, but not giving any internet

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb, ethernet

I have a realtek ethernet cord, along with two different ethernet-to-USBC adapters. I live in a university apartment complex that provides Wi-Fi and ethernet. The ethernet cord, when connected to the outlet in the wall to my MacBook Pro 2019 13-inch Ventura 13.1, can be seen in "Network" as USB 10/100/1000 LAN; however, it does not provide any internet access from that. Here is all that I have tried, and know:

- I've changed the IP address for it.
- I've added two DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)
- I've renewed the DHCP license.
- I've installed all relevant drivers from Realtek as well as the adapters.
- I've booted my macbook into safe mode and tried connecting to ethernet there.
- I've gone to recovery mode and disabled System Integrity Protection
- The ethernet works for my roommate, who has a Windows computer. All he had to do was plug it in, and then it worked.
- I've been on the phone with my apartment's internet providers to make sure everything was going right on their end

I don't understand what's wrong with my Mac, and why it refuses to play nice with ethernet.

Comment: What IP address do you get?  Make sure you are getting it automatically and you are not setting it yourself (manual). Also, remove your DNS settings.

Comment: Does it work over WiFi? Did you run Network Diagnostics?